# Scope clarification: Mediums and efficiency of those mediums on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've never been quite clear on the scope of this site (Yeah, I've read the scope many times, but different people interpret it differently), even after 5 gold badges and 21 questions, and I'm doubtful about this one so I'll ask:

Can I ask about software mediums, their efficiency, and when they should / should not be used?

For example, I want to know if DLLs are a performant way to offer a library to projects of various languages rather than transcribing the lib code to each of those languages natively. I have more specifics to ask about, but that should be enough to decide whether it would be on/off topic here.

Comment: After achieving the tumbleweed badge for this I suppose no one else knows either :P